# How to setup a collectionView (or TableView) with NSFetchedResultsController and multiple fetched entities

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have read here that the way to fetch multiple entities with 1 NSFetchedResultsController is to use a parent child inheritance model. I have such a model:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq1ZB.jpg

As you can see, TextPost,VideoPost, and ImagePost all have Skill as a parent entity. I am trying to make a single collectionView for which all three children show up. I am a little confused as to how to set the delegate methods though...

Here is the code for the view controller

```
class Timeline2ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var postsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var skillName: String?

    fileprivate lazy var skillFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Skill> = {
        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Skill> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Skill")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", self.skillName!)
        let timeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [timeSort]

        let skillFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return skillFetchedResultsController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            try skillFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("SkillFetchError")
        }
    }
}
extension Timeline2ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sectionInfo = skillFetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { return 0 }
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = postsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "pcell", for: indexPath) as? PostViewCell else { return fatalError("unexpected Index Path")
        }
        let post = skillFetchedResultsController[indexPath.row] /* This is the line im not sure about
        cell.background
        return cell
    }
}
```

Since only 1 entity is actually, returned, I am not sure how to access an element at a specific index path. For instance skillFetchedResultsController[indexPath.row] would I think only have 1 entity - the skill itself. I really want to be accessing its children. Do I have to somehow subclass skillFetchedResultsController and return only the children Im interested in?

Edit: with @pbasdf suggestions - I have this model:

[image]

Now when I create an entity like so:

```
        guard let appDelegate =
         UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
             return
         }
         let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let textPost = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "TextPost", into: managedContext) as! TextPost
        textPost.text = "test text post"
        try! managedContext.save()
```

and I setup my fetched results controller to look at "Post2" like so:

```
    fileprivate lazy var skillFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Post2> = {
        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Post2> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post2")
//        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "skill = %@", self.skill!)
        let timeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [timeSort]
        let skillFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return skillFetchedResultsController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        do {
            try skillFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch _ as NSError {
            print("SkillFetchError")
        }

    }
```

I see no returned results in:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sectionInfo = skillFetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { return 0 }
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

Do I somehow need to link the two? Like create the Post object and the TextPost object at the same time? When I try and fetch TextPost objects directly it works.

Comment: Let me check I understand your model: a Skill can have many Posts (and Posts relate to only one Skill), but each Post can either be a TextPost, ImagePost or VideoPost?

Comment: @pbasdf correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your model.  You should create a `Post` entity, and make it the parent entity of `TextPost`, `VideoPost`, and `ImagePost`.  If your subentities have any attributes in common, move them from the subentities to the `Post` entity.  Then establish a one-many relationship from `Skill` to `Post`.

Your FRC should fetch `Post` objects (which will by default include all the subentities), using a predicate if necessary to restrict it to those `Post` objects related to your desired `Skill` object, eg.

```
NSPredicate(format:"skill.name == %@",self.skillName!)
```

Comment: Is NSPredicate(format:"skill.name == %@",self.skillName!) the way to go? As opposed to NSPredicate(format:"skill == %@",self.skill!) ?

Comment: If you have the `Skill` object itself, go with that (ie. `"skill == %@",self.skill`).  I used `skillName` based on your code, but it's more efficient to use the object.

Comment: I updated the model to what I think you are referring to. Check the edit in the post.

Comment: You have implemented it as I described, but I can't immediately see why your TextPosts are not being fetched by the Post2 FRC and hence not appearing in the collectionView.  I'll give it some thought.

Comment: I think it basically works as you described. I must be doing something wrong in my code. I created this bare-bones app to show that it works as you describe: https://github.com/AlexMarshall12/test-nfc-fetch-children in case you or anyone else wants to try it.